# Trigger Chain Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have this code:

```
this.array = [];
initArrayClicked() {
    this.clearArr()
    .then(this.addOneToArray.bind(this))
    .then(this.addTwoToArray.bind(this));
}
```

I have button that when I clicked on it this function called and at the end of this chian promise `this.array` value is `[1, 2]` and thats okay.

The problem starts when I clicked the button twice quickly and `this.array` at the end has different value every time (`[1, 2, 1, 2]`, `[2, 1, 2]`).

I wish that when I clicked the button my final result will be `[1, 2]` doesn't matter how qucikly I clicked the button. I guess that the problem is that the chain of the promises didn't finsish and I start it from the begging and that caused the unwanted result.

I tried to look for a solution but I couldn't found.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english!

Comment: can you post your other functions. addOneToArray, addTwoToArray

Comment: It's not the problem, but note that you're assuming that your promises will never be rejected. And taking @JayLane's point further: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Comment: If you get four rapid clicks, do you want two results (`[1, 2]`, then `[1, 2]` again), or **one** result (just one `[1, 2]`)?

Comment: When you do the MCVE, please ensure that it demonstrates why you'd need promises for this at all (in the above, you don't; so presumably you've simplified and gone a bit too far), and a thorough, clear explanation of the results you want.

Comment: One result with `[1, 2]`. That means that when I start  the function I want to stop the old cahinging. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: It's not my real code in my project.. It is just example to an issue that I have.  @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @Sagie: Right. For people to be able to help you without wasting your time and theirs, it's important that the example be a *representative* example. See that link I mentioned above for details: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `click` handler to `null` until `Promise` chain is completed, then reattach `click` handler to element

```
let handleClick = () => {
  button.onclick = null;
  this.array = [];
  this.clearArr()
  .then(this.addOneToArray.bind(this))
  .then(this.addTwoToArray.bind(this))
  .then(() => button.onclick = handleClick.bind(this /* set `this` here */))
}

button.onclick = handleClick.bind(this /* set `this` here */);
```

Comment: I gave here poor example that one button trigger this function. I my real project I have a lot buttons that trigger this function, so that won't help me.

Comment: You can perform a loop on the `<button>` elements and set each `click` handler to `null`, at last `.then()` loop to reattach event handler to

Answer (score 0):

You've said you want four rapidly-repeating clicks to only result in a single pair. To do that, block repeated calls to `initArrayClicked`:

```
this.array = [];
this.arrayBusy = false;
initArrayClicked() {
    if (!this.arrayBusy) {
        this.arrayBusy = true;
        this.clearArr()
        .then(this.addOneToArray.bind(this))
        .then(this.addTwoToArray.bind(this))
        .catch(error => { /*...handle errors, don't throw new ones...*/ })
        .then(() => { this.arrayBusy = false; })
    }
}
```

Note the inline error handling. For the final `then` to be triggered, that `catch` must not throw an error or return a promise that rejects. I assume you want to do that because you're not returning the promise chain out of the function, so nothing *else* will be able to handle errors from it. The structure would be different if that weren't the case.

Comment: There isn't a way that I can force stop the current chaining promises and start over?

Comment: @Sagie _"There isn't a way that I can force stop the current chaining promises and start over?"_ That is not original question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Sagie: Promises have no "cancel" or "abort" semantics. If you update your question with a [mcve] -- a **representative** example of what you're doing -- I can probably suggest an alternative that does what you want. But not on the basis of the question as it stands now.